# Event listener multiplies result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular

I want to get current coordinates of a clicked point on Google Maps.

My code:

```
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);


getCoords() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => {
        console.log(event.latLng);
    });
```

Binding to Google Maps:

```
  <div #map id="map" (click)="getCoords()"> </div>
```

What I am getting on click on the map is:

- 1 click: nothing happens
- 2 click: current coordinates
- 3 click: current coordinates x 3
- 4 click: current coordinates x 5
- etc.

How do I turn my function to expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that, since you bind `getCoords` for the click event in HTML, you are calling `google.maps.event.addListener` each time you click on the map. 
Try removing the click handler from html:
`<div #map id="map"> </div>`

And call `google.maps.event.addListener` somewhere in initialization, so the event listener gets created only once.